# Size of the circles in the Kibana Tile map visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5, cartography

In Kibana we have a visualization called *Tile map* which has has several options to customize, such as map type.

My question is about one of this types: **Shaded Circle Markers** which is basically about changing colors based on value.

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/5.0/tilemap.html) says:

> Displays the markers with different shades based on the metric aggregation’s value.

and that's correct, but I don't understand why some bubbles are bigger than others.

I assume that this may be due to the distortion caused by [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection), which which is well presented by [Tissot's indicatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix), but I didn't find any source which confirming my hypothesis.

Could you confirm my suspicion or explain in other way this behavior?

[image: map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer from Elastic Team Member who confirmed my suspiction. This distortion is caused by Mercator projection.

> Link to Elastic Search forum: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/size-of-the-circles-in-kibana-tile-map-visualization/108395